# user-facing email validation

Tags: javascript, validation, email

I'd like to have a generic way for validating user provided email with a bias toward ease of use. Does the following do so in a clear way for implementations that have the `URL` interface available? The sample input below is only intended to exercise the range of expected input and demonstrate it works. The UI is not in scope and varies separately--the solution is only intended to provide input validation with usable feedback for implementations.

Any feedback welcome on the style, approach, etc.

```
function validEmail(input=''){
    const emailPatternInput = /^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{4,253}$/, emailPatternUrl = /^[^@]{1,64}@[a-z][a-z0-9\.-]{3,252}$/i;
    let email, url, valid = false, error, same = false;
    try{
        email = input.trim();
        // handles punycode, etc using browser's own maintained implementation
        url = new URL('http://'+email);
        let urlderived = `${url.username}@${url.hostname}`;
        same = urlderived === email;
        valid = emailPatternInput.test( email );
        if(!valid) throw new Error('invalid email pattern on input:' + email);
        valid = emailPatternUrl.test( urlderived );
        if(!valid) throw new Error('invalid email pattern on url:' + urlderived);
    }catch(err){
        error = err;
    };
    return {email, url, same, valid, error};
}

[
 'user+this@はじめよう.みんな'
, 'stuff@things.eu'
, 'stuff@things'
, 'user+that@host.com'
, 'Jean+François@anydomain.museum','هيا@יאללה'
, '试@例子.测试.مثال.آزمایشی'
, 'not@@really'
, 'no'
].forEach(email=>console.log(validEmail(email), email));
```

Comment: Unless you are writing a library yourself, you should use a library for this, there are so many rules and gotchas in email validation. And if you are writing a library yourself, then you should check out your competition.

Comment: Given the lack of competency and the failure of existing solutions in place across the internet I made this solution. It is the only one of its type and works reliably as demonstrated by the exercising of code as shown in the samples. Relegating responsibility to solutions provided by others is a logical fallacy and reflects poor exercise of due diligence with respect to the work. I disagree and it is for these reasons. Thanks for the comment nonetheless. It affords us and opportunity to challenge this common assertion.

Comment: A competent implementation should follow the email address RFC; https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373724/7602

Comment: ["If you really need to be sure an email address is valid, you’ll need to send an email to it that contains a code or link for the recipient to perform a second authentication step. And if you’re doing that, then there is little point in using a regex that may reject valid email addresses."](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid the habit of declaring multiple variables in the same line. In most cases, they're hard to read especially when they get long. The only one exception I'd do this would be if everything is short enough to read, like your `let` line. But that one has other issues as well: why the two `false`s? and why initialize with `false` when they end up as other types (string for `email` and `url`, and an `Error` instance for `error`)?

A general rule for `try-catch` is to only use it for *unexpected errors*, like for calls to other functions. Never use it as a control structure. In your case, you're using thrown errors to bail out of the block. Throwing an error inside your own `try-catch` is an anti-pattern. It's better to use a conditional instead.

Then theres the inconsistent use of syntax, like the use of template literals here but not there, or the one-time assignments to a `let` which can just be a `const`, etc.

Now, doing away with the `try-catch`, the only thing that's complex is the relationship between `error` and `valid`. Everything else is just a value resulting from an expression, which in the following example... is just a series of `const`.

In your code, you compute validity twice and determine which error to use based on which check failed. This probably led to the strange complexity in your version of the code, you had to bail out with your error before it did the next check. But you can flip it around. You can use the check to determine the error. Then define `valid` based on the presence or absence of that error.

```js
function validEmail(input = '') {
  const inputPattern = /^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{4,253}$/
  const emailPattern = /^[^@]{1,64}@[a-z][a-z0-9\.-]{3,252}$/i
  const email = input.trim()
  
  // handles punycode, etc using browser's own maintained implementation
  const url = new URL(`http://${email}`)
  const urlDerived = `${url.username}@${url.hostname}`

  // Same-ness is the same regardless of errors. Bumping up.
  const same = urlDerived === email;
  
  // Test for incorrectness, null if ok.
  const error = !inputPattern.test(email) ? new Error(`invalid email pattern on input: ${email}`)
    : !emailPattern.test(urlDerived) ? new Error(`invalid email pattern on url: ${urlDerived}`)
    : null
  
  // The presence/absence of the error determines validity.
  const valid = !Boolean(error)
  
  return { email, url, same, valid, error }
}

[
  'user+this@はじめよう.みんな',
  'stuff@things.eu',
  'stuff@things',
  'user+that@host.com',
  'Jean+François@anydomain.museum',
  'هيا@יאללה',
  '试@例子.测试.مثال.آزمایشی',
  'not@@really',
  'no'
].forEach(email => console.log(validEmail(email), email));
```

Comment: Perhaps it would help your argument to share that [using `const` over `let` can help avoid bugs with accidental reassignment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653/244085)

Comment: Thanks Joseph, this is useful feedback. The try-catch is initially used to trap unexpected _user_ input errors. I can short-circuit by throwing errors where their input doesn't match the url and the URL interface will throw errors as well depending on input and sequence, using the same general type for all errors in a UI. Valid and same are different comparisons to expose for implementations for use in messaging to the user UI--that separates the concern while removing the need to do the same operation (message the UI and discard the result is the expected use).